# Postgres - How to know if restore was performed since last check

Tags: postgresql

I need to take some actions if database restore was performed on specific database I'm "monitoring".
I know that if the database was dropped and recreated then the oid would be different:

```
select oid from pg_database where datname = 'test'
```

However, if only the objects where dropped and restore was executed then the oid would remain the same.

Please note that the restore can be with backup taken from the same setup or from a different setup.

How can I now that restore was performed?

Comment: You can create an event trigger and log whatever you want: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-triggers.html

Comment: If you use `-c` and `-C` with `pg_restore` you would get a DROP/CREATE DATABASE and a different `oid`. In addition to event triggers you could audit the Postgres log for object changes, as example [PGAudit](https://www.pgaudit.org/).